# views combined exposed date filters

Tags: datetime, views

I want to have the following exposed filtering:

- Older events
- Events in the next 7 days
- Events in the next 30 day

My date is already set as a exposed filter with the relative date "now". But that works only for one of the options, the other filters need now + 7 etc. But I cannot enter different relative dates (see screen). Is there a way to combine those three filters?

[image: grouped filters]

Comment: this is a long issue here https://drupal.org/node/1764902 the fields are hide use firebug to show that field and put date value that may solve ur problem.

Comment: I found the fields via firebug but the value does not save :(